# Visual Studio 2010 very slow

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010

Core I7 + 16gb ram + raid 0 stripping + win7 ultimate 64bit

When I compile my web project with Visual Studio 2010 ultimate 32bit, it takes long time (the total build time!!!) and usually appends when I change something into the ASPX code.

Compiling single projects is very fast, but after compiling, it takes a lot of time to finish the overall process.

Any suggestions?

ps I already tried to disable antivirus and intellitrace

```
Build Summary
-------------
00:00.561 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Infrastructure.Data\CodcastWeb.Infrastructure.Data.csproj
00:00.546 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Web.Client\CodcastWeb.Web.Client.csproj
00:00.196 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Database\CodcastWeb.Database.dbproj
00:00.174 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Web.Client.Tests\CodcastWeb.Web.Client.Tests.csproj
00:00.097 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Application\CodcastWeb.Application.csproj
00:00.092 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Infrastructure.CrossCutting\CodcastWeb.Infrastructure.CrossCutting.csproj
00:00.085 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Application.DTOs\CodcastWeb.Application.DTOs.csproj
00:00.081 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Application.Tests\CodcastWeb.Application.Tests.csproj
00:00.077 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Domain\CodcastWeb.Domain.csproj
00:00.034 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.DistributedServices\CodcastWeb.DistributedServices.csproj
00:00.013 - Success - Debug Any CPU - CodcastWeb.Modeling\CodcastWeb.Modeling.modelproj

Total build time: 06:27.796

========== Build: 11 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Why did you undo Felix's edit?

Answer (score 0):

Are your projects 'Web Sites' or 'Web Applications', as the former take a lot longer to compile than the later (as the compiler goes through each file individually, getting slower the more files the site has).

Check for file sizes, are there any dependencies (such as the output from another project or library) that are getting copied the the output bin directory that have to be moved, as this could have attached resources that are getting copied - hence the slow down is a file-copy operation.

Looking at your build output, is there anything missing?  Each item takes seconds, so unsure where the 6-hour total comes from. Does it seem to just hang after the last item?  In which case it's sound like Visual Studio would benefit from being reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Layer Diagrams in your modelling project they can take a long time to validate.  Try removing the model project from your solution temporarily and recompiling just to test if that is the source of the slowdown.